# Some Commits Are Not Synced With Secondary Branch

Tags: git

I seem to be in some sort of commit sync hell with my master and secondary branch after a few merges down the road.

I've attempted to do cherry-pick to see if I can copy commits over, but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Since the files are still different from the master and the secondary branch.

I'm wondering is whats the best and safest way to do a sort of branch reset on my secondary with master?

It appears all my stable changes went to master, but I need my secondary to be correctly synced up. I was thinking of deleting the secondary branch and start fresh from master, but it seems like there would already be a sort of function to not have to do that.

Thank you.

Comment: The question does not give enough details: depending on the actual state of your repository, the solution could either be a rebase, another merge, a hard reset. While "commit sync hell" is evocative, we don't know what the problem really is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to switch to a specific commit `git reset` is better option.

```
$ git checkout master                   # will switch master branch
$ git log                               # see all the commit you have done 
$ git reset --hard <commit hash>        # switch to a commit
```

If you want to switch a commit and keep the changes you need to Soft Reset.
 `$ git checkout --soft <commit hash>`

Comment: Wouldn't your example be effecting the master branch? And wont reset only work on the current branch your on that has that commit?

Comment: Actually what have you done? you have changed on secondary branch and want to remove the changes & start from fresh copy of master ?

Comment: Actually, I want to attempt to keep the changes on secondary if possible. But I was considering of doing a clean restart, but would take more time rewriting some code. All I have been doing is

Comment: say secondary branch= `b1`. You can switch to master branch and checkout to a new branch(say `b2`) then it starts from the fresh copy of master. All the changes you have done in `b1` will remain unchanged. when you need that codes simply switch to `b1`. You can also compare two branches. `$ git diff b1..b2 //show you what is in b2 that is not in b1` and vice versa.